# How to Deploy Nuxt.Js Application on cPanel

Tags: vue.js, github, nuxt.js, cpanel, web-deployment

I Have Created a Nuxt Application and I want to Deploy it on my client's Domain.
The Domain was purchased from Namecheap.com and Hosting was Purchased from Couchdeck.net.

I have cloned my private repository from GitHub into cPanel.
[screenshot of the repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSVxf.png)

I have created a node.js application from the 'setup node js app' section.
[screenshot of node js app created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC77N.png)

[Here is The Link to My Github Repository](https://github.com/nahezsakharkar/ashwini-hospital.git)

I have searched every corner of the internet to find a tutorial for deployment but failed to find it. All I want is a detailed walk-through for deployment please help me out.

I hope this information is enough for you to give me an answer.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You checked this I guess? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnuxt%5D+cpanel

Comment: yes, I have. but no one has seemed to get their answer and neither do i.

Comment: The first doesn't work? What's the issue there?

Comment: I have no idea about this deployment. the questions they have asked have confused me.
Heroku Deployment is so easy but why cant I deploy that easily on cpanel.
Link of heroku deployed app : https://ashwini-try.herokuapp.com